# How to turn off scroll inside section in collectionView (UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout)?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Could you help me with my problems please.
I have collection view with different type of section:

1. Scrolling horizontally,
2. Tabs
3. Tab content.

I made tab as section and when user press tab I just call collectionView.scrollToItem(at indexPath + 1) and it is work great.
I have problems with content section. I made is like horizontal carousel and I have to turn off scroll at it.
This is the code of this section.

```
fileprivate static var tabContantLayout: NSCollectionLayoutSection {
    get {
        let sectionBackground = NSCollectionLayoutDecorationItem.background(
                elementKind: "background")
        let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(1))
        let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
        
        let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
            widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
            heightDimension: .estimated(1))
        let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
        let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
        
        section.decorationItems = [sectionBackground]
        return section
    }
}
```

If I change section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior to `none` all items will be located vertically one by one.

[collection view screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPdjc.png)

Please, If you know say how I can turn off scroll only in this section? Thanks